# Unable to load ZF2 with correct(?) include_path

Tags: nginx, zend-framework2, php

So, I'm still newbie for all Unix stuff and now I face a problem which make me mad :) I also asking my friend, more experienced programmer, but he cant find answer too.
So, I trying to start zf2 application based on zend-skeleton with nginx and php5-fpm.

```
$ sudo service nginx status
 * nginx is running

$ sudo service php5-fpm status
php5-fpm start/running, process 3389

$ ps aux | grep php
root      3389  0.0  0.3 145520 13624 ?        Ss   15:40   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)                    
www-data  3392  0.0  0.1 145520  4968 ?        S    15:40   0:00 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data  3393  0.0  0.1 145520  5324 ?        S    15:40   0:00 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
somebud+  3551  0.0  0.0   5908   840 pts/1    S+   15:55   0:00 grep --color=auto php

$ ps aux | grep nginx
somebud+  3172  0.5  0.6 184412 24944 ?        Sl   15:33   0:07 gedit /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
root      3368  0.0  0.0  15196  1092 ?        Ss   15:40   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  3369  0.0  0.0  15720  2080 ?        S    15:40   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  3370  0.0  0.0  15376  1516 ?        S    15:40   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  3371  0.0  0.0  15376  1516 ?        S    15:40   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  3372  0.0  0.0  15376  1516 ?        S    15:40   0:00 nginx: worker process
somebud+  3554  0.0  0.0   5908   840 pts/1    S+   15:55   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

This is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/testing.dom

```
server {
      listen      80;
      server_name testing.dom;
      root /var/www/testing.dom/public_html/CommunicationApp/public/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(php|phtml)?$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(git|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|ico)?$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$ {
        expires 1h;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

My include_path is in the /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini like this:

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/var/www/testing.dom/public_html/library/Zend"
```

This is what in this Zend folder:

```
$ sudo ls  /var/www/testing.dom/public_html/library/Zend/
    Authentication  Code     Db Escaper       Filter  InputFilter  Log     Mime       Paginator    Server          Stdlib  Uri    XmlRpc
    Barcode     Config   Debug  EventManager  Form    Json     Mail    ModuleManager  Permissions  ServiceManager  Tag     Validator
    Cache       Console  Di Feed          Http    Ldap     Math    Mvc        ProgressBar  Session         Test    Version
    Captcha     Crypt    Dom    File          I18n    Loader       Memory  Navigation     Serializer   Soap        Text    View
```

Is this right library folder?

And this is my /var/www/testing.dom/public_html/CommunicationApp/public/index.php

```
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

$temp = get_include_path();
var_dump($temp);

// Decline static file requests back to the PHP built-in webserver
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server' && is_file(__DIR__ . parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH))) {
    return false;
}

// Setup autoloading
require '../CommunicationApp/init_autoloader.php';

// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

So, if I enter testing.dom in browser I got still this:

```
string(62) ".:/usr/share/php:/var/www/testing.dom/public_html/library/Zend"
```

And nothing else.

And this is nginx error.log:

```
2014/10/17 16:11:29 [error] 3369#0: *8 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.' in /var/www/testing.dom/public_html/CommunicationApp/init_autoloader.php:53
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/testing.dom/public_html/CommunicationApp/public/index.php(17): require()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/testing.dom/public_html/CommunicationApp/init_autoloader.php on line 53" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: testing.dom, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "testing.dom"
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved! If you got such headache try to define your ZF2_PATH in fastcgi_params like this:

```
fastcgi_param  ZF2_PATH          /var/www/testing.dom/public_html/library/;
```